# EC2 machine in an ELB of 10 EC2 instances gets redirected to, via ELB when down

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an ELB supporting 10 EC2 instances. All contain the same PHP code. When I update one EC2 instance with the new code, the web server and mysql needs to be restarted. This causes a downtime of around 10 seconds. During this downtime, sometimes a request is forwarded to this particular EC2 instance and the client gets a RTO error due to unavailability of services catered by that EC2 instance by the ELB forwarding.

How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Before updating your code, remove the instance from the load balancer. Wait for connection draining. Then update the instance and re-add to the load balancer.

Comment: But the problem is that the EC2 instances are in an auto scaling group.

Comment: ASG is a big item to leave out of your question. Please update your question on how you are deploying your instances, AMIs plus any other details that are needed to help you.